# How do I use an existing HTTP session for install4j?

Tags: install4j

Using install4j 7.0.2/7.0.3 here.

The main program starts the auto-updater via `ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication`.

We need to use an existing HTTP (HTTPS actually) session to even access the download site, let alone download stuff.

Is it possible to pass the session ID to the auto-updater so that it will include it in the HTTP headers?
Or is there generally a way to pass HTTP header data to the autoinstaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Check for update" action and the "Download file" action are the ones that make HTTP connections in the update downloader.

Both of them have a "Request headers" property. You can set installer variables for the update downloader with arguments when invoking `ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication`:

```
-Vheader1=value1
```

Then you can use them with the syntax

```
${installer:value1}
```

in the request header properties.